# Can I convert the Provenance data in Apache NiFi to Prov-O and put in to an RDF graph?

Tags: apache-nifi, ontology

I would like to somehow take the provenance data that is generated by Apache NiFi and convert it to Prov-O format.  I would then like to store the generated triples in the Prov-O format in to a Jena database.  I am most interested in the conversion of the NiFi provenance data.  Has anyone converted it to Prov-O.  That is the W3C standard for creating provenance ontology information in an RDF store.

Comment: You can use the SiteToSiteProvenanceReportingTask to extract the Provenance data in a flow. You could then build a flow to convert it to PROV-O and put it somewhere. I'm not aware of anything pre-built to handle that conversion, though.

Comment: How could I build a flow to convert to Prov-O ?  Would I need some kind of mapper?  Not sure how that would work (that is the core of my question)  Thanks for answering!